# What's this kind of syntax in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax

```
$test= <<<EOF

....

EOF;
```

I have never see it before. What's it used for?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is called **[HEREDOC syntax](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)**, which is a way to define strings, on multiple lines, with variable interpolation.

Quoting the manual page:

> Heredoc text behaves just like a
>   double-quoted string, without the
>   double quotes. This means that quotes
>   in a heredoc do not need to be
>   escaped, but the escape codes listed
>   above can still be used. Variables are
>   expanded, but the same care must be
>   taken when expressing complex
>   variables inside a heredoc as with
>   strings.

*(There is more to read, that I didn't copy-paste from the manual page)*

And, as a very quick and simple example:

```
$a = 'World';
$string = <<<MARKER
<p>
  Hello, $a!
</p>
MARKER;
echo $string;
```

It will give you this output:

```
Hello, World!
```

And this HTML source:

```
<p>
  Hello, World!
</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"nested case"* ?

Comment: It's just a way to define a string without having to escape any special characters. It doesn't _do_ anything, really, so the question seems a bit odd.

Comment: FYI The NOWDOC is the new HEREDOC: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: NOWDOC, when first created, was different : it was using simple-quotes only, and there was no variable interpolation ;;; NOWDOC with double-quotes (and variables interpolation) has been added later, for consistency -- and HEREDOC still exists.

Answer (score 0):

That would be [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc

> Blockquote
>   A third way to delimit strings is the heredoc syntax: <<<. After this operator, an identifier is provided, then a newline. The string itself follows, and then the same identifier again to close the quotation.
>
> The closing identifier must begin in the first column of the line. Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is the [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax.

Just in case you are wondering what interest it can have vs the regular string delimiters:

```
// These strings contain the same thing '"'"
$s1 = '\'"\'"';
$s2 = "'\"'\"";
$s3 = <<<EOS
'"'"
EOS
```

No more quote escaping.
A typical use case for me is when I need to store in a string some HTML code I have copy/pasted.